# Creation of PhoneGap SQL Lite DB with user settings

Tags: javascript, sql, database, cordova

Im trying to create my first phonegap application (targeting iOS).
The purpose of the app is very simple, but im running in to some errors with the SQL Lite database.
The goal is simply to save some settings from the user in the DB, and then show some general statistics based upon it.
So the app should be able to insert/update the user settings (gender, county, age).
The DB should eventually be a global one, containing all user inputs, and then show statistics based on that - but for the prototype that im making, a local database is fine.

The code for creation/inserting/updating/select a database from an online tutorial looks good to me, but nothing really happens. Im not even sure that the database really is created, which is should be according to phonegap docs?

// SCRIPT CODE //

```
var db; 
var shortName = 'WebSqlDB'; 
var version = '1.0'; 
var displayName = 'WebSqlDB'; 
var maxSize = 200000;

function onDeviceReady() {
    var db = window.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize); 
}

function errorHandler(transaction, error) { 
    alert('Error: ' + error.message + ' code: ' + error.code); 
}

function successCallBack() { 
    alert("DEBUGGING: success"); 
}

init(){
    alert("DEBUGGING: we are in the onBodyLoad() function");
    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.'); 
        return;
    }
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql( 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(UserId INTEGER NOT 
    NULL PRIMARY KEY, County TEXT NOT NULL, Gender TEXT NOT NULL, Age INTEGER NOT NULL)', [],nullHandler,errorHandler); 
    },errorHandler,successCallBack);
        }
    $('#lbUsers').html('');
    db.transaction(function(transaction) { 
       transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM User;', [], 
         function(transaction, result) { 
          if (result != null && result.rows != null) { 
            for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) { 
              var row = result.rows.item(i); 
              $('#lbUsers').append('<br>' + row.UserId + '. ' + 
    row.County + ' ' + row.Gender + ' ' + row.Age); 
            } 
          } 
         },errorHandler); 
     },errorHandler,nullHandler);
   return; 
}

function AddValueToDB() { 
    if (!window.openDatabase) { 
       alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.'); 
       return; 
     }
    db.transaction(function(transaction) { 
       transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO User(County, Gender, Age) 
    VALUES (?,?,?)',[$('#txCounty').val(), $('#txGender').val(), $('#txAge').val()], 
         nullHandler,errorHandler); 
       });
    ListDBValues(); 

     return false; 
}
```

// HTML CODE //

```
<form>
    <label for="county">County:</label>
    <input id="txCounty" type="text" name="county" id="county" value="" placeholder="County" />
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Gender:</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2a" value="male" checked="checked">
    <label for="radio-choice-h-2a">Male</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-h-2" id="radio-choice-h-2b" value="female">
    <label for="radio-choice-h-2b">Female</label>
    </fieldset>
    <label for="age">Age:</label>
    <input type="number" name="age" id="txAge" value="" placeholder="Age" />
    <input type="button" value="Add record" onClick="AddValueToDB()">
    <input type="button" value="Refresh" onClick="ListDBValues()">
</form>
<span style="font-weight:bold;">Currently stored values:</span> 
<span id="lbUsers"></span>
```

In the console, it says that 'ListDBValues, AddValueToDB and init is not defined'.
I know i put init as my onDeviceReady..
I could really need some guidelines here! Much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your javascript with lint: http://www.javascriptlint.com/

```
$ jsl process yourcode.js
```

phonegap js fails silently, lint can help in debugging your code.